# What method was used in Google Maps to calculate the area from LatLong?

Tags: google-maps

I want to know what method was used in Google Maps JS API to find the result of the `computeArea()` function from lat long. Can you show me the formula of `computeArea()`?

This for my undergraduate thesis literature.

Comment: I suppose it's not that easy.  Think of the shape of the Earth: more or less an ellipsoid, but slightly egg shaped (not 100% symmetric up or down the equator).  Try figuring it out with a perfect sphere first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [investigate geometry library](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry) for that purpose but unfortunately no non-minified / non-obfuscated versions of Google Maps API is available.

Below is provided the *similar* function for computing the area (in square meters) of a polygonal area:

```
function computeArea(latLngs) {
    var pointsCount = latLngs.length,
            area = 0.0,
            d2r = Math.PI / 180.0,
            radius = 6378137.0,
            p1, p2;

    if (pointsCount <= 2)
        return 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++) {
        p1 = latLngs[i];
        p2 = latLngs[(i + 1) % pointsCount];
        area += ((p2.lng() - p1.lng()) * d2r) *
                (2 + Math.sin(p1.lat() * d2r) + Math.sin(p2.lat() * d2r));
    }
    area = area * radius * radius / 2.0;
    return Math.abs(area);
}
```

**Example**

```js
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 5,
        center: { lat: 55.761838, lng: 37.626980 },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

    var coords = [
        { lat: 55.761838, lng: 37.626980 },
        { lat: 57.624476, lng: 23.997321 },
        { lat: 52.228649, lng: 21.025482 },
        { lat: 50.692479, lng: 30.645169 }
    ];

    var latLngs = coords.map(function(coord) {
        return new google.maps.LatLng(coord.lat, coord.lng);
    });

   

    
    var area = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: coords,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    area.setMap(map);

    var areaSize = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(latLngs);
    document.getElementById('panel').innerHTML = 'google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea: ' + areaSize / 1000;
    var areaSizeAlt = computeArea(latLngs);
    document.getElementById('panel').innerHTML += '<br>custom computeArea: ' + areaSizeAlt / 1000;


}



function computeArea(latLngs) {
    var pointsCount = latLngs.length,
   area = 0.0,
   d2r = Math.PI / 180.0,
   radius = 6378137.0,
   p1, p2;

    if (pointsCount <= 2)
        return 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++) {
        p1 = latLngs[i];
        p2 = latLngs[(i + 1) % pointsCount];
        area += ((p2.lng() - p1.lng()) * d2r) *
                (2 + Math.sin(p1.lat() * d2r) + Math.sin(p2.lat() * d2r));
    }
    area = area * radius * radius / 2.0;
    return Math.abs(area);
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
}

#panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: i want to add literature how google maps can do this function computeArea(), how they get the area result..? what formula used in there..?

Comment: ohh,, okay, thanks.. can you explain to me about the parameters..? what is d2r? i want to write it as description in equation math..

Comment: `d2r` is a multiplier for converting degrees into radians

Comment: what mean of % in `% pointsCount` ? and does this variable `area +` mean that area result always positive?

Comment: are `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea()` with `computeArea()` used same formula? if it use different formula, what the different both of them?

Comment: expression `(i + 1) % pointsCount` is used for getting the next vertex coordinates, the `area` value could be either positive or negative depending on the coordinates but `Math.abs(area)` returns the absolute value

Comment: heyy vadim, in formula `(2+Math.sin(p1.lat()...` where is `2` come from?